# Пытаюсь сверстать вот это на html и css, но не получается. Почему?

Tags: html, css

[image: Вот то, что я хочу сверстать, но у меня никак не получаетсятекст курсивом]

Вот такую штуку хочу сверстать, но у меня выходит коряво. Помогите как это правильно сверстать?

```css
.opisanie {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 740px;
}

.price {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 27px;
}

body img {
  margin: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Рацион 800</h1>
  <p class="opisanie">Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции обеспечивает широкому
    кругу.
  </p>
  <p class=price>399</p>
  <img src="image 1.png" alt="">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: У вас разметки совсем нет, поэтому и не получается.
html book в помощь http://htmlbook.ru/
Ищите в сторону блочной верстки, вам потребуются <div> и их стили CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оборачивайте элементы создавая как бы блоки - видите например текст слева, а изображение справа - оборачиваете тексты в одну обёртку и изображение в другую и так легче будет их расставить, а также работать с внутренними элементами.

```css
div {
  display: block;
}
.opisanie{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.price{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: max-content;
}
.container {
  width: 580px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
.container:before {
  left: -15px;
}
.container:after {
  right: -15px;
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.tipo-img {
    width: 45%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.info {
  width: 55%;
}
.crest {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.crest:before,.crest:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}
.crest:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.crest:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flexbox">
      <div class="info">
        <h1>Рацион 800</h1>
        <p class="opisanie">Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности позволяет
            выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия. 
           Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что начало повседневной
            работы по формированию позиции обеспечивает широкому кругу.
        </p>
        <p class=price>399</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tipo-img">
        <img src="image 1.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="crest"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо большое!

Comment: Приму это на заметку